# Correct way to use overridden SCSS variables in Angular components

Tags: angular, sass

I am using the Bulma CSS framework in an Angular 9 project.

I imported Bulma in the *styles.scss* file and overridden two variables prior to import:

```
$family-primary: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
$primary: hsl(204, 71%, 53%);

@import "~bulma";
```

I wish to use the modified `$primary` variable in a component.

```
.logo:hover{
    color: $primary;
  }
```

This leads to an error of `Undefined variable: $primary`.

When I import the Bulma variables file (`@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/all";`), it works. However, the `$primary` variable is not overridden correctly. I assume this is because the component is importing the original file (containing the original values for variables), which is, in turn, overriding my changes to the variable in the styles.scss file.

What is the correct way to import variables overridden in styles.scss in components?

I would appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to override styles from an imported library, then you need to define your overrides after the library has been imported. So just move your import to the top and you should be good.

Comment: On the Bulma documentation it advises override before importing. That seems to work. So, for example the default font changes. Importing prior to overriding doesn’t work. 

My confusion lies with how to use css framework variables in components (which I believe are boundaried).

Answer (score 0):

For my Angular projects I use a shared SCSS file between components. When you import Bulma into `styles.scss` it will compile SCSS to CSS whose classes you can use in component HTML files. But you can't use variables, functions and in component SCSS files. They will be only available in `styles.scss`.

To use Bulma (overridden) variables etc. in component files you can use a shared SCSS file

**styles.scss**

Import complete Bulma so it will compile classes that you can use in component html files

```
@import 'override'    
@import '~bulma/bulma';
```

**override.scss**

```
$family-primary: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
$primary: hsl(204, 71%, 53%);
```

**shared.scss**

Do not import complete Bulma again, but only what you need between components SCSS files.

```
@import 'override';
@import '~bulma/sass/utilities/initial-variables';
@import '~bulma/sass/utilities/derived-variables';
```

**component.scss**

```
@import 'shared';

.logo:hover{
  color: $primary;
}
```